# Terribly slow synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I'm trying to write game of life on many threads, 1 cell = 1 thread, it requires synchronization between threads, so no thread will start calculating it new state before other thread does not finish reading previous state. here is my code

```
        public class Cell extends Processor{
            private static int count = 0;
            private static Semaphore waitForAll = new Semaphore(0);
            private static Semaphore waiter = new Semaphore(0);
            private IntField isDead;
            public Cell(int n)
            {
                super(n);
                count ++;
            }
            public void initialize()
            {
                this.algorithmName = Cell.class.getSimpleName();
                isDead = new IntField(0);
                this.addField(isDead, "state");
            }
            public synchronized void step()
            {
                int size = neighbours.size();
                IntField[] states = new IntField[size];
                int readElementValue = 0;
                IntField readElement;
                sendAll(new IntField(isDead.getDist()));
                Cell.waitForAll.release();
    //here wait untill all other threads  finish reading
                    while (Cell.waitForAll.availablePermits() != Cell.count) {
                    }
    //here release semaphore neader lower 
                Cell.waiter.release();
                for (int i = 0; i < neighbours.size(); i++) {
                    readElement = (IntField) reciveMessage(neighbours.get(i));
                    states[i] = (IntField) reciveMessage(neighbours.get(i));
                }
                int alive = 0;
                int dead = 0;
                for(IntField ii: states)
                {
                    if(ii.getDist() == 1)
                        alive++;
                    else
                        dead++;
                }
                if(isDead.getDist() == 0)
                {
                    if(alive == 3)
                        isDead.setValue(1);
                    else
                        ;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(alive == 3 || alive == 2)
                        ;
                    else
                        isDead.setValue(0);
                }
                try {
                    while(Cell.waiter.availablePermits() != Cell.count)
                    {
                        ;
                      //if every thread finished reading we can acquire this semaphore
                    }
                    Cell.waitForAll.acquire();
                    while(Cell.waitForAll.availablePermits() != 0)
                        ;
//here we make sure every thread ends step in same moment
                    Cell.waiter.acquire();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

processor 
class extends `thread` and in run method if i turn switch on it calls `step()` method. well it works nice for small amount of cells but when i run abou 36 cells it start to be very slow, how can repair my synchronization so it woudl be faster?

Comment: Just as a note, multithreading isn't a good way to accomplish this kind of thing except for personal experimentation. As you have found, the performance may be horrendous due to threading overhead, while a single-threaded solution that calculates the new state from the old over the whole board may work better.

Comment: Yes, this is for personal experimentation, but there are only 36 threads and they are doing rather very simply computations, thats why i'm so suprised, maybe there is, for sure there is better synchronization method then my with two `semaphores`

Comment: If there is one thread per cell, then why does instance method `Cell.step()` need to be synchronized?  Why would multiple threads ever need to contend for access to this method on the same `Cell`?

Comment: i want synchronization over `sendall` so every cell has same data

Comment: @whd, if your comment about `sendall` was a response to me, then I think you have missed the point.  Java synchronization is always relative to the monitor of a specific object.  For an instance method with the `synchronized` keyword, that object is the one on which the method is invoked.  Multiple threads all invoking the same `synchronized` method on different objects therefore are not synchronized with each other at all.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Sorry, I didnt express clearly what i mean by `synchronization`. I dont mean synchronization over method(in java context) i just mean synchronization in more general context . I want to every Cell to call `sendall()` method and then wait untill every other finish it. I'm using 2 sempahores because with one semaphore i was not able to `relase' without any troubles. ie: if one thread has already finished job and want to release it and other is still in first while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using large numbers of threads tends not to be very efficient, but 36 is not so many that I would expect that in itself to produce a difference that you would characterize as "very slow".  I think more likely the problem is inherent in your strategy.  In particular, I suspect this busy-wait is problematic:

```
Cell.waitForAll.release();
//here wait untill all other threads  finish reading
while (Cell.waitForAll.availablePermits() != Cell.count) {
}
```

Busy-waiting is *always* a performance problem because you are tying up the CPU with testing the condition over and over again.  This busy-wait is worse than most, because it involves testing the state of a synchronization object, and this not only has extra overhead, but also introduces extra interference among threads.

Instead of busy-waiting, you want to use one of the various methods for making threads suspend execution until a condition is satisfied.  It looks like what you've actually done is created a poor-man's version of a `CyclicBarrier`, so you might consider instead using `CyclicBarrier` itself.  Alternatively, since this is a learning exercise you might benefit from learning how to use `Object.wait()`, `Object.notify()`, and `Object.notifyAll()` -- Java's built-in condition variable implementation.

If you insist on using semaphores, then I think you could do it without the busy-wait.  The key to using semaphores is that it is being able to acquire the semaphore (at all) that indicates that the thread can proceed, not the number of available permits.  If you maintain a separate variable with which to track how many threads are waiting on a given semaphore at a given point, then each thread reaching that point can determine whether to release all the other threads (and proceed itself) or whether to block by attempting to acquire the semaphore.

Comment: Looks like there is alot to learn for me, thanks didnt hear abour cyclicbarrier before!